# Using C# NAudio to open an Audio Stream and save that Audio Stream back in Small Chunks

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I have an audio stream in 4 formats (.asx, .m3u, .mp3 and .pls) and I would like to read that audio stream into C# NAudio and convert that audio into small 15 second chunks.

```
    String url = "";
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

    using (Stream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (Stream stream = WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        {

           byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];

           int read;

           WaveFormat waveFormat = new WaveFormat(8000, 8, 2);
           using (WaveFileWriter writer = new WaveFileWriter(@"C:\\Users\\Public\\Music\\Sample Music\\Test.wav", waveFormat))
           {
               while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
               {
                   ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                   writer.Write(buffer, 0, read);

                   var a = DateTime.Now - start;

                   if (a.TotalSeconds >= 15)
                   {
                       break;
                   }
               }
            }
         }
     }
```

Each piece of audio created in the following function comes back as static.

1. How should I set up the WaveFormat?
2. Why is it complete static?